# How to search and replace in a line using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file content like this

> select b.id as cli_id,b.login as cli_login, b.pname as cli_name,
>   b.cname as cli_company, b.phone as cli_phone, b.email as cli_email,
>   (select (value / 1048576) from Limits where limit_name='disk_space'
>   and id=b.limits_id) as Client_Package, b.cr_date, (select
>   FROM_UNIXTIME(value,"%Y-%m-%d") from Limits where
>   limit_name='expiration' and id=b.limits_id) as Client_expire,
>   If(b.status=0,'Active','Inactive') as Cli_Status, a.name as dom_name,
>   If(a.status=0,'Active','Inactive') as Dom_Package, a.cr_date as
>   dom_create, (select FROM_UNIXTIME(value,"%Y-%m-%d") from Limits where
>   limit_name='expiration' and id=a.limits_id) as dom_expire, (select
>   (value / 1048576) from Limits where limit_name='disk_space' and
>   id=a.limits_id) as Dom_Package, round((a.real_size / 1048576)) as
>   Dom_usage from domains a, clients b where (select
>   FROM_UNIXTIME(value,"%Y-%m-%d") from Limits where
>   limit_name='expiration' and id=a.limits_id and
>   (FROM_UNIXTIME(value,"%Y-%m-%d") between '2011-08-01' and
>   '2011-12-01') ) and a.cl_id=b.id group by a.id;

this all comes in a single line

in that i want to replace the date part alone in this format

> between '2011-08-01' and '2011-12-01'

The script runs every friday , suppose if i run this on 10th month means.

the script need to change the value in the file like this

> between '2011-09-01' and '2012-01-01'

every time the month alone need to change in this format

> between 'current month -1month' and 'current month + 3 months'

```
sed -i 's/between  '2011-08-01' and '2011-12-01'/'between '$(date --date="- 1 month" +%Y-%m)-01' and '$(date --date="+ 3 months" +%Y-%m)-01'/g file1
```

in this code iam trying to find and replace

but it shows this error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unterminated `s' command

What mistake iam doing can any 1 explain?

Answer (score 1):

The expression isn't properly quoted. You start with 's/... but end with ... /g. No quote there. This is what I ran and it worked fine:

```
sed -i "s/between '[0-9-]*' and '[0-9-]*'/between '$(date --date'-1month' +%Y-%m-01)' and '$(date --date'+3months' +%Y-%m-01)'/g" file1
```

Comment: Hi, 
this command not works for me..it gives infiniete intergers output using ctr+c only i need to break that output

Comment: sed -i "s/between '[0-9-]*' and '[0-9-]*'/between '$(date -v'-1m' +%Y-%m-01)' and '$(date -v'+3m' +%Y-%m-01)'/g" /var/tmp/p.sql
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try `date --help' for more information.
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try `date --help' for more information.